# Show that $xz +x'y + zy = xz + x'y$ (Boolean Algebra)

Tags: boolean-algebra, boolean

My best guess is that somehow $$xz + x'y = zy$$
I know that $$A + A'B = A + B$$  but can that be applied here since there is an extra variable?
Is there a relevant rule I'm missing?

Question 25 from https://web.mit.edu/6.111/www/s2007/PSETS/pset1.pdf

Comment: A hint: note that $xz = xz+xzy$

Comment: It seems to be wrong. If you cancel out the identical terms in the left and right sides of the equality, it simplifies to $zy = 0$. Also, $A + A'B = A + B + AB$ is correct.

Comment: @user3257842 You can't cancel out in Boolean algebra.

Comment: The keyword here is the consensus theorem.

Comment: If $+$ means "xor" and $xy = x*y = x \wedge y$ then it's just addition and multiplication mod $2$, so cancellation works fine.   

$xz +x'y + zy =x(y+y')z +x'y(z+z') + zy = xyz + x'yz + zy + xy'z + x'yz'= (x+x')zy + xy'z + x'yz' = zy + zy +  xy'z + x'yz' =  xy'z + x'yz'$

Comment: @user3257842 The standard notation for Boolean Algebras is that $+$ denotes "or". And this is consistent with the other exercises from the link (for example $a+a=a$). So no, here $+$ doesn't means "xor".

Comment: That's somewhat confusing, but yeah, cancellation won't work if $+$ denotes "or".

Answer (score 2):

Since $x + x' = 1$, one gets
\begin{align}
xz +x'y + zy &= xz +x'y + (x + x')zy \\
&= xz + x'y + xzy  + x'zy \\
&= xz(1 + y) + x'y(1+z) \\
&= xz + x'y
\end{align}